# Search query -> Show all pages except certain template

Tags: query, search, post-type

These are my arguments for the search query:

```
$args = array(
 's' =>$s,
 'post_type' => array( 'post', 'p24_cases', 'page')
);
```

Using these arguments, the search results will show all pages that contain the search word. I want to show all pages, except for the page template called 'bedankt' (thanks in Dutch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### REWORKED ANSWER TO ANSWER THE QUESTION

In order to exclude all pages with a certain template, all you need to do is to run a `meta_query` to exclude all pages with the custom field `_wp_page_template` set to `bedankt`. Remember, WordPress saves the template assigned to a page as a hidden custom field called `_wp_page_template`

With this in mind, we can do the following

```
$args = [
    's'         => $s,
    'post_type' => ['post', 'page', 'p24_cases'],
    'meta_key'  => [
        [
            'key'     => '_wp_page_template',
            'value'   => 'bedankt.php',
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        ]
    ]
];
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER - misread question

You simply need to get the post ID of that page, anf then pass it as an array to `post__not_in`

```
'post__not_in' => [1], // Replace 1 with actual page ID
```

Or pre PHP 5.4

```
'post__not_in' => array( 1 ), // Replace 1 with actual page ID
```

Comment: Well, there are multiple pages in that template, and there is a possibility that in the future, more pages will be added. This way, I only except certain pages, but I want all pages that use the template 'bedankt' to be excepted from the query.

Comment: AGGGHHH crap, sorry, I missed that part, sorry about that. Will rework my answer ;-)

Comment: Haha, it's fine :p I'll see your answer soon ;)

Comment: See my updated answer ;-)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! This worked like a charm. Bedank! (Dutch is not so different from Afrikaans :p)

Comment: Don't forget the `.php` extension. Also, if you page template is saved in a subfolder, your format must be `subfolder/name-of-template.php`

Comment: Haha, .php extension won't be forgotten :p Luckily I'm not new to PHP :)

Comment: Yes, I can read and understand Dutch, the only issue I have is when you talk, you talk a bit to fast, but if you slow down, I can follow and understand. Enjoy ;-)